# 502 Gateway error - ngnix on django application

Tags: django, production, http-status-code-502

I have an already running sites one is the main (user-facing) and one staging website. They're in django and have been running for years, but during one of my builds i started encountering a "502 bad gateway error" when I clicked on some of the pages. The changes I made were not towards any of the ngnix configs or even server changes. Before it used to run smoothly.

However this issue remains on Chrome (works fine on safari) and when i clear cache on chrome it starts to work again for around 10 minutes and then something or the other gives bad gateway. Also if i copy paste the link into a different chrome profile it'll probably work and vice versa. (the different profiles on chrome don't have any different extension or different setting..). It honestly seems random and i don't know how to solve this at all.

Any help/ tips would be appreciated